# Which version of Tizen Wearable should I choose for the development of watchfaces?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, watchface

I just started with the development of a watchface for Tizen/Samsung watches (native application). Should I select the latest Wearable version 5.5 in Tizen Studio expecting that it is backwards compatible with older devices? Or should I select an older version like 3.0 so that the watchface runs reliably on older devices?

The way to go in Android is to always choose the latest SDK version and when there is a function, that is not supported on older versions, to make a case distinction and implement the code for those older versions.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start development using [Tizen 4.0](https://developer.tizen.org/tizen/tizen/tizen-4.0) as it is stable now. Tizen 5.5 will be released soon but some of current devices may not get Tizen 5.5 updates (Gear S3, Gear Sport etc). So, to cover the most devices you should pick Tizen 4.0.

Comment: Thanks Iqbal. So, that means that a watchface made with Tizen 4.0 will run on newer devices, but not on devices with Tizen 3.0 or less?

Comment: Tizen Platform is trying to keep API compatibility as much as possible. And, In case of watchface, it is stable module in Tizen, I think it will work correctly with older and newer version, if it works correctly with 4.0 platform.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: One thing still puzzles me. If i set my project to version 4.0 and try to launch it on the emulator with Tizen 3.0, it will not work. I get the error:

"processing result : Operation not allowed [-4] failed"

Is this normal? If yes, it is worrying. If there are still users with Tizen 3.0 or less on their watches, they will not be able to install my app. I have tried to find out what percentage of Tizen users have 3.0, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Don't worry ! No device is currently on the market with Tizen 3.0 or lower (Except Gear S2 with 2.3.2)

Comment: I own a Galaxy Watch 46mm and it is currently using version 4.0. I don't know if I could develop in version 5.0 for it, I guess I couldn't.